# A remote process' base address and snapshot

Tags: c++, windows, memory, process

A quick couple of questions that are exploding my brain right now: is the base address retrieved from a MODULEENTRY32 struct (created from a snapshot of a remote process, and referring to the remote process' module) the real address in memory or a relative address? If it is relative, what's it relative to?

Second: Are the base addresses of any other modules in a remote process' snapshot relative to the remote process' base address or are they real addresses in memory? The documentation says that the hModule member of a MODULEENTRY32 struct is "A handle to the module in the context of the owning process," so I think that's implying it's a relative address, but I'm not sure.

Just in case what I'm saying is completely out of context, here's some partial code:

```
DWORD getProcBaseAddress(DWORD targetPID) {
    hModuleSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, targetPID ); 
    MODULEENTRY32 me32;
    me32.dwSize = sizeof( MODULEENTRY32 );
    Module32First( hModuleSnap, &me32 );
    _tprintf( TEXT("Proc Base Address = 0x%08X"), (DWORD) me32.modBaseAddr);
    return (DWORD) me32.modBaseAddr;
}
```

This might be functional code. targetPID is the process ID of my target process. Anyways, my question is referring to the modBaseAddr. Thanks in advance for any help or consideration. Bonus points if you can refer me any good articles or sources about relative and physical addressing :-]

Comment: It is a handle to the module in the context of the process. Module handles are virtual addresses in the process address space. So I guess in your terminology they are "real". But the real question is "Why are you snooping on another process?" Better would be to establish a proper IPC mechanism.